# Why runXXX is not part of MonadTrans definition?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

The `MonadTrans` document says:

> Each monad transformer also comes with an operation runXXX to unwrap the transformer, exposing a computation of the inner monad.

So I wonder why `MonadTrans` is not defined as

```
class MonadTrans t where
  type p :: *
  type r :: * -> *
  lift:: Monad m => m a -> t m a
  run :: t m a -> p -> m (r a)
```

to eliminate the above clause? Is that the above definition not generic enough? If so, which monad transformer does not fit for this definition?

**UPDATE**

Adjusted a little bit to enable different result type.

Comment: Why do you need the extra `v` type?

Comment: To run a `MonadTrans` you usually need additional information. For example, to run `MonadCont` you need to provide a continuation to pass on, etc.

Comment: What about `runWriterT :: WriterT w m a -> m (a, w)`?

Comment: em... this require to adjust the interface a little bit.

Comment: I think the problem would be that some transformers require extra information to run, while some don't, and some could conceivably require many extra arguments to run.  This is probably the reason why there isn't a generic `run` for `MonadTrans`

Comment: Well, for those require nothing to run, just let `v` to be `()`. If you need many arguments to run, it is something like `(a,b,c...)`.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't solve the problem, `runWriterT` only takes 1 argument, and only needs 1 argument, but your `run` function always takes 2!  What if I wrote a custom `runMyApp :: ReaderT Config (StateT S m) a -> Config -> S -> m (s, a)`?  And currying everything is not a very popular design choice in Haskell.  I think the idea is to just let the writers of each `MonadTrans` instance choose how they want to run it without restricting it to needing to be runnable at all.  Obviously if it can't be run then it isn't much use, but there could be a use case that I haven't thought of.

Comment: What truly defines a monad transformer is being able to lift monadic actions into the transformer, not being able to run it.  It's analogous to monads, being defined by bind and return, instead of being able to extract a pure value out at the end.  Many monads can't have their pure values extracted anyway!  I would argue that the reason why `MonadTrans` only has `lift` is because _that's all it needs to function_.  It may seem more convenient to have a consistent `run` function for all transformers, but I think in the end it would just be annoying.  Use the domain specific run method instead.

Comment: @bheklilr, that's a good point.  Show a good use of `run` as an *abstraction*, i.e. where you use it without knowing which particular monad transformer you are working with.  Otherwise, why bother with all the complexity it introduces?

Comment: @luqui I think from a theoretic point of view, you'd probably want `run` to be the inverse of `lift`, so `run . lift = lift . run = id`, but this presents many challenges to get the types lined up in a usable way, particularly for transformers that require arguments to `runXXX`, and I think it puts too much of a restriction on something that functions without that law.  It'd be like saying that all monads must have an inverse to `return`, it'd make writing custom monads a nightmare, and it's impossible for `IO` (excluding `unsafePerformIO` as usual).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no universal interface for running monad transformers.  For example, try running `LogicT` or `ContT` or `FreeT` using your interface.

Even if you could generalize your interface to handle all of these example, you would still be missing the key ingredient: laws.  Type class methods should obey equations that allow you to reason about code that uses the type class interface without consulting the source of specific instances.  For example, the `lift` method from `MonadTrans` must obey these to laws:

```
lift (return x) = return x

lift (m >>= f) = lift m >>= \x -> lift (f x)
```

There are nice theoretical reasons why `lift` should obey these laws, which become more apparent if you write the laws in this point-free style:

```
(lift .) return = return                        -- fmap id = id

(lift .) (f >=> g) = (lift .) f >=> (lift .) g  -- fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g
```

In other words, `(lift .)` is a functor between two kleisli categories and `lift` is therefore a monad morphism.

A lot of thought goes into defining type classes like `Functor`, `Monad`, and `MonadTrans`, and the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) is a great place to start learning more about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I was thought about this again and again, and in additional to the accepted answer I wanted to add more comments.

As we have seen so far, it is not easy to define the `run` interface for **ALL** possible `MonadTrans`. But there is exactly one implementation that is guaranteed to be able to suit all cases:

```
class MonadTrans' t where
    type r m a :: *
    lift':: Monad m => m a -> t m a
    run :: Monad m => t m a => r m a
```

With fist glance it seems to solved the problem...

But wait, a `MonadTrans'` implementer can then treat:

```
instance MonadTrans t => MonadTrans' t where
   type r = t
   lift' = lift
   run = id
```

So actually this definition does not constraints anything and the clause about `runXXX` is not able to be eliminated...

Anyway, the way `run` does above is actually have an interesting usage. In [this post](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/TypeClass.html#Haskell1) the author claim that only a single type class in Haskell is sufficient to have all(most?) type class benefits like overloading etc.

```
class C l t | l -> t where ac :: l -> t
```